# How to disable expand/collapse on double click in XUL table

Tags: javascript, tree, firefox-addon, dom-events, xul

I have a XUL tree in my Firefox extension. When I double click on a row, the row collapses or expands. How can I disable this behavior (so that collapsing and expanding can only occur by clicking on the plus/minus signs)? I'd like to reserve double clicking for something else.

I've tried to disable the default action and event propagation like below, but this didn't work. The event handler was executed but did not prevent the collapsing.

```js
tree.addEventListener("dblclick", onTreeDoubleClick, true);

onTreeDoubleClick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tree gets the event before you do. AFAIK the only way to get it earlier is to register a capturing event handler on the parent element of the tree:

```js
tree.parentNode.addEventListener("dblclick", onTreeDoubleClick, true);
```

Of course, that assumes that the parent element doesn't contain element other than the `<tree>`, otherwise you catch the events on these elements as well - but you can always put the `<tree>` element into its own `<box>` element just for that.